# Pull private DockerHub image with Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, devops

I'm learning Terraform. After completed the "getting started" tutorial with Terraform (with Docker), I tried to pull a private Docker image but I have the following error:

`Error: Unable to read Docker image into resource: unable to pull image <registry>/test:latest: error pulling image <registry>/test:latest: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <registry>/test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

The configuration is the following:

```
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address     = "registry-1.docker.io"
    config_file = pathexpand("~/.docker/config.json")
  }
}

...

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "<registry>/test:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}
```

If I `docker pull` everything works fine, so I assume is a configuration issue

I tried to change the host field in the configuration. I also tried to rename the image.

Comment: `"<registry>/test:latest"` is not a valid repository url...

Answer (score 0):

config_file never worked for me even though I was logged in with docker login.

So I had to use username/password directly like this:

```
registry_auth {
  address  = "registry-1.docker.io"
  username = "dockerhub-username"
  password = "dockerhub-pass"
}
```

Note: you can use your password for dockerhub or your token if you create one before hand.